# Automatically change item height in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview. When starting my app, the item height of the vertical recyclerview is stretched according to textview with the highest height (as shown in the picture). When I scrolled to the last item, this height was changed. However when I scroll back to the first item, this height has not been reset.

How can I set the vertical recyclerview height depending on the height of the textview content in the horizontal recyclervew.

Below is my picture and code

Sorry for my bad English skills.

**VerticalRecyclerviewAdapter**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_food_menu, null, false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return new MenuViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder menuViewHolder, int i) {

    Category category = menuArrayList.get(i).getCategory();
    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItemArrayList = (ArrayList<MenuItem>) menuArrayList.get(i).getMenuItems();

    String headerMenu;

    //Set text by language
    if (LanguageUtils.getCurrentLanguage().getCode().equals(context.getString(R.string.language_japanese_code))) {
        headerMenu = category.getNameJp();
    } else {
        headerMenu = category.getNameEn();
    }

    menuViewHolder.txtHeaderMenu.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.character_title_category) +" "+ headerMenu);

    ItemRecyclerViewAdapter itemRecyclerViewAdapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(context, menuItemArrayList,this.mListener);

    menuViewHolder.recyclerListFood.setHasFixedSize(true);
    menuViewHolder.recyclerListFood.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    menuViewHolder.recyclerListFood.setAdapter(itemRecyclerViewAdapter);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return menuArrayList.size();
}

public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView txtHeaderMenu;
    protected RecyclerView recyclerListFood;

    public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtHeaderMenu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeaderMenu);
        this.recyclerListFood = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerListFood);
    }
}
```

**HorizontalRecyclerviewAdapter**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public FoodRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_food, null);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    //if you need three fix imageview in width
    return new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.FoodRecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodRecyclerViewHolder itemRecyclerViewHolder, int i) {
    MenuItem menuItem = this.menuItem.get(i);
    final Item item = menuItem.getItem();

    String name;
    String price = Utils.priceAndTaxToString(item.getPrice(), item.getTax());
    String tax = Utils.getTaxToString(item.getTax());
    //Set text with language
    if (LanguageUtils.getCurrentLanguage().getCode().equals(context.getString(R.string.language_japanese_code))) {
        name = item.getNameJp();
    } else {
        name = item.getNameEn();
    }



    itemRecyclerViewHolder.txtItemName.setText(name);
    itemRecyclerViewHolder.txtItemPrice.setText(Utils.increaseFontSizeForPath(price,tax,0.75f));

    String imgPath = item.getImg();
    try {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .fitCenter()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(FileUtil.getUrlImgFile(context, imgPath))
                .apply(options)
                .into(itemRecyclerViewHolder.imItem);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        itemRecyclerViewHolder.imItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_no_image);
    }


    itemRecyclerViewHolder.onItemClickListener(new FoodRecyclerViewHolder.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            OrderDialog orderDialog = new OrderDialog(context, item, mListener);
            orderDialog.show();
        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return menuItem.size();
}


public static class FoodRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected ImageView imItem;
    protected TextView txtItemName;
    protected TextView txtItemPrice;

    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public FoodRecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
        this.txtItemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemPrice);
        this.imItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imItem);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onItemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

[image: Step1]

[image: Step2]

[image: Step3]

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If yes, could you share the solution, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setHasFixedSize(boolean)

> void setHasFixedSize (boolean hasFixedSize). RecyclerView can perform
>   several optimizations if it can know in advance that RecyclerView's
>   size is not affected by the adapter contents. RecyclerView can still
>   change its size based on other factors (e.g. its parent's size) but
>   this size calculation cannot depend on the size of its children or
>   contents of its adapter (except the number of items in the adapter).
>   If your use of RecyclerView falls into this category, set this to
>   true. It will allow RecyclerView to avoid invalidating the whole
>   layout when its adapter contents change.

So you should use `RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);` in your case. Your code should be `menuViewHolder.recyclerListFood.setHasFixedSize(false);`

Comment: Hi John Le, thanks for your answer but it's not working with me

Comment: Did you try to use `RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)` for both of  `RecyclerView`s?. The one is vertical `RecyclverView` and the other is horizontal `RecyclerView`

Comment: Yes, I added it at both.